# Can xgboost.DMatrix be silent by set "silent=True"

Tags: python, xgboost

I am learning XGBoost. I want to finish a demonstration with XGBoost python api.
when I use the function "xgboost.DMatrix" that data is set a file,silent is set True. However, the function "xgboost.DMatrix" always output some message "[23:28:44] 1441x10 matrix with 11528 entries loaded from file_name". was I setting error parameters? [reference](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting. The silent value is taken and passed to the Wrapper, but it seems like the wrapper doesn't really use it !

This shows the appropriate code https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/c_api/c_api.cc#L202

Which says:

```
int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(const char *fname,
                            int silent,
                            DMatrixHandle *out) {
  API_BEGIN();
  if (rabit::IsDistributed()) {
    LOG(CONSOLE) << "XGBoost distributed mode detected, "
                 << "will split data among workers";
  }
  *out = new std::shared_ptr<DMatrix>(DMatrix::Load(fname, false, true));
  API_END();
}
```

i.e. even though silent is a argument, it is not used in the function anywhere ... (very weird)

So, it seems right now, if you're using any of the wrappers (Python, R, julia, etc) the silent functionality for DMatrix won't work.

Comment: I noticed that https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1742 was already created (probably by you). Added a pull request to fix it at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/1794